# What is the difference between the diet and workout regimes of lingerie/underwear models and fitness enthusiasts/marathon runners?

Tags: diet, workout-routines, training, programs

I was curious as to what the difference was regarding the diet and workout regimes of underwear models compared to say marathon runners and fitness enthusiasts.

Surely they both monitor nutrition to maximise fat loss etc, but what part of their diet and regime causes the difference in body shape?

Which would be best to obtain an 'underwear'-type body as opposed to an athletic runner?

Answer (score 2):

Don't run so much; massive mileage tends to reduce muscle mass. Sprinters, OTOH, tend towards highly-developed musculature, also not a typical "model look".

Marathon runners (of the professional variety) tend to carry far less bodyfat than a typical model.

It also makes a *big* difference what "model look" you're after; a *lot* of models are "skinny fat" and not remotely fit. But in general, the diet/exercise regime of models is less intense than that of an athlete, because they're not athletes.